# SUBSTRING? Can I use this command to eliminate some words before the Name

Tags: sql, substring

Quick question here I have this syntax to get the Case Name:

`SELECT CCH.Style AS CaseName`

And it returns the persons name but before the name it has **"In the Matter Of:"** then the person's name. Can I use use a command such as **"SubString"** to get rid of that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. `SUBSTRING(string, start, length)` is the syntax. In your case, the query would be `select substring(cch.style,17) as CaseName ... `

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Because the string probably doesn't appear anywhere else in the style, `REPLACE()` might be simpler:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CCH.Style, 'In the Matter Of:', '') AS CaseName
```

This will work whether or not the phrase is in the `Style`.